# Git client throwing error

Tags: git, github

I am trying to clone a project from GitHub but I keep getting this error:

```
github.com[0: 207.97.227.239]: errno=Result too large
fatal: unable to connect a socket (Result too large)
```

This is the version of the Git client I am using:

```
git-gui version 0.12.0.23.ga91be
git version 1.6.4.msysgit.0
```

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: maybe more details would help. What was the exact command you issued? On what operating system?

Comment: This issue seemed to resolve itself. The error occured while I was using my laptop at work, but once I got home and tried again it worked fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This issue seemed to resolve itself. The error occured while I was using my laptop at work, but once I got home and tried again it worked fine.

Comment: @Rob move to a different location and try again

Answer (score 4):

I met this problem just now. After I changed from git:// to https:// , it works. If you are using bower, this may help: [Bower install using only https?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15669091/bower-install-using-only-https) .

Answer (score 1):

Another two possible problem are

1. you may have some firewall software in your computer (especially for office computer) like Norton (Symantec Management Client service).
2. you may have some firewall in your router.

I meet the first one, since normally home router has empty filters