# Bower install using only https?

Tags: git, bower, git-clone

I am trying to set up Bower on a build server at our organization's data center, but `git`'s port does not appear to be open on the data center's firewall.  I can use the git command line client to clone via `https://[repo]`, but not `git://[repo]`.

Is there a switch or preference which will instruct bower to perform git clone using `https` rather than the `git` protocol?

I've looked at the source, and considered changing the resolution code to replace `git://` with `https://`, but I figured I'd ask before I go to those lengths.

Comment: possible duplicate of [git: convert "git" urls to "http" urls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722807/git-convert-git-urls-to-http-urls)

Answer (score 632, accepted):

You can make git replace the protocol for you. Just run:

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

to use HTTPS protocol instead of Git.

Comment: I feel really dumb. I kept trying the portion of the command prior to .insteadOf thinking that @Sindre was telling us to use git **insteadOf** git. Good grief these english-like commands.

Comment: In case anyone else applies this answer and then wonders later how to back out that global configuration change (like me), it's: `git config --global --unset url."https://".insteadOf`

Comment: You can also omit `--global` and it will add the configuration to the local `.git/config`.

Comment: That was good hint, but I was getting `Connection reset by peer` error. But replacing `https` with `http` solved this problem. For me this command worked well: `git config --global url."http://".insteadOf git://`

Comment: thanx a lot. super usefull command in case of closed ssh (22) port

Comment: This worked but in my case, the git config file was not in USER_HOME, had to use -f switch to specify the path of the config file.

Comment: didnt work for me. I am getting this error:bower not-cached    git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#*
bower resolve       git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#*
bower ECMDERR       Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git", exit code of #128

Additional error details:
fatal: '.insteadofgithub.com/jquery/jquery.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Comment: On Windows machine, the global configuration file is .gitconfig under user's home folder, e.g. C:\Users\[username]. However if %HOME% is not defined, git will using %HOMEDRIVE% while git from bower will use %USERPROFILE% instead. Whereas these two variables might be different. On my machine, one is U:, the other is C:\Users\myusername. So the bower still used git:// whatever I tried. It took me a while to figure this out. So write it down in case anybody falls into the same situation.

Comment: AnthonyY, how do I define %HOME% ?

Comment: @VincentGauthier I found it easiest to manually add the content to the .gitconfig in the home directory.  You can pick it up from the other location or it will look like `[url "https://"]
 insteadOf = git://`

Comment: If you need it for BOWER, you should use it without the global param.

Comment: @VincentGauthier In Windows, launch System Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables -> SystemVariables -> New -> Add a variable named HOME and set its value to your desired path

Comment: while this does work, it doesnt solve the problem... i want bower to use http, not git to rewrite my urls to http...

Comment: I thought the ["shorthand-resolver" setting in .bowerrc](https://github.com/bower/spec/blob/master/config.md#shorthand-resolver) would have the same effect, but it does not. Anyone know why?

Comment: this allow us to bypass the entreprise proxy blocking all non http request

Comment: Thanks, this answer allowed me to download bower packages through Visual Studio 2015 behind a firewall.

Answer (score 2):

Building on the answer from @Sindre, I wrote a little helper function in BASH which lives in my `~/.bashrc` file. Call it just as you would `grunt`, except now it's called `nngrunt`. Enjoy!

```sh
function nngrunt
{
    # Add a section to the global gitconfig file ~/.gitconfig that tells git to
    # go over http instead of the git protocol, otherwise bower has fits...
    # See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15669091/bower-install-using-only-https
    git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://

    # Run grunt w/ any supplied args
    grunt "$@"

    # Now cleanup the section we added to the git config file
    # Of course we have our own extra cleanup to do via sed since the unset command
    # leaves the section around
    # See http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/git-config-unset-does-not-remove-section-td7569639.html
    git config --global --unset url."https://".insteadOf
    sed -i 's/\[url "https:\/\/"\]//' ~/.gitconfig
    sed -i '/^$/d' ~/.gitconfig
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me
`git config --global url."git://".insteadOf https://`