# Unable to Connect to GitHub.com For Cloning

Tags: git, github, git-bash, git-clone

I am trying to clone the [angular-phonecat git repository](https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat), but I am getting the following message when I enter the command in my Git Bash:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat.git  
Cloning into 'angular-phonecat'...  
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:  
github.com[0: 204.232.175.90]: errno=No error
```

Answer (score 391, accepted):

You are probably behind a firewall. Try cloning via https – that has a higher chance of not being blocked:

```
git clone https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat.git
```

Comment: thanks it helped me too. I just updated url line inside .git > config ==> to https ://git@git...xxx

Comment: worked for me but had to disable 2 factor auth when cloning from private organization repo

Comment: Any advice on what to do if HTTPS is getting timed out as well?

Comment: @STEEL Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I had tried all of those `insteadOf` commands multiple times with different options and noticed that my `~/.git_config` was messed up. I removed all of them, disabled my Mac OSX Firewall and now everything works.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work if a dependency has dependencies with "angular/angular-phonecat".

Comment: Thanks https:// works for me looks like my system firewall blocks git:// scheme

Comment: If the issue occurred during either npm or yarn install, change the
default requesting protocol from **git://** to **https://** by
running, **git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://**

Also, you can revert this change later by running, **git config --global url."git://".insteadOf https://**

Comment: @gjw80 had a point in one of the above comments. Below answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31044011/3625752. Will be helpful in setting up the proxy of the company into git config and then try with git clone will work

Answer (score 374):

You can make git replace the protocol for you

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

See more at SO [Bower install using only https?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15669091/bower-install-using-only-https)

Comment: thanks man. i was also hving same issue while work from office internet. which doesnt allow SSH url.

Comment: Is there a way to make this work only for domain github.com?

Comment: `git config --global url."https://github.com".insteadOf git://github.com`

Comment: i would mark this as the perfect answer, for those are using repo/yocto way

Comment: This can also be undone in `~/.gitconfig` if you only want to apply it temporarily.

Answer (score 31):

I had the same error because I was using proxy. As the answer is given but in case you are using proxy then please set your proxy first using these commands:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://proxy_username:proxy_password@proxy_ip:port
git config --global https.proxy https://proxy_username:proxy_password@proxy_ip:port
```

Comment: what proxy_username??

Comment: To use the default proxy credentials, use the following commands:
`git config --global http.proxy http://:@proxy_ip:port` and `git config --global https.proxy https://:@proxy_ip:port`

Comment: The below commands also work for me.

git config --global http.proxy http://proxy_ip:port
git config --global https.proxy https://proxy_ip:port

Answer (score 17):

Open port 9418 on your firewall - it's a custom port that Git uses to communicate on and it's often not open on a corporate or private firewall.

Comment: if you are already using https:// and still having issues, try this answer. i just had to add a 9418 port trigger on my router and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem but just realized that GitHub must be one of the sites my ISP's "child safe" filter blocks by default. Presumably there are some, er, adult code repositories out there. I added github.com to the Allow List on my ISP account page and all is working now. Might be worth checking if you have a similar filter in place.