# Strange Bower / Git error (error code #128, could not chdir to 'Y:/')

Tags: node.js, git, osx-mavericks, bower

I just installed Node/NPM/Yeoman on a fresh install of OS X 10.9.2. Xcode tools are all installed. I pulled down a repository of a current project and ran `bower install` to install dependencies. Output looks like this:

```
bower angular#1.2.6         not-cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.6
bower angular#1.2.6            resolve git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.6
bower json3#~3.2.6          not-cached git://github.com/bestiejs/json3.git#~3.2.6
bower json3#~3.2.6             resolve git://github.com/bestiejs/json3.git#~3.2.6
bower es5-shim#~2.1.0       not-cached git://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim.git#~2.1.0
bower es5-shim#~2.1.0          resolve git://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim.git#~2.1.0
bower jquery#~1.10.2        not-cached git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#~1.10.2
bower jquery#~1.10.2           resolve git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#~1.10.2
bower bootstrap#~3.0.3      not-cached git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#~3.0.3
bower bootstrap#~3.0.3         resolve git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#~3.0.3
bower angular-resource#1.2.6       not-cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-resource.git#1.2.6
bower angular-resource#1.2.6          resolve git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-resource.git#1.2.6
bower angular-route#1.2.6          not-cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route.git#1.2.6
bower angular-route#1.2.6             resolve git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route.git#1.2.6
bower angular-file-upload#0.4.1    not-cached git://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload.git#0.4.1
bower angular-file-upload#0.4.1       resolve git://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload.git#0.4.1
bower angular-mocks#1.2.6          not-cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks.git#1.2.6
bower angular-mocks#1.2.6             resolve git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks.git#1.2.6
bower angular-scenario#1.2.6       not-cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-scenario.git#1.2.6
bower angular-scenario#1.2.6          resolve git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-scenario.git#1.2.6
bower angular-mocks#1.2.6             ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks.git", exit code of #128

Additional error details:
fatal: Could not chdir to 'Y:/': No such file or directory
```

Interestingly, the package that the `ECMDERR` occurs on changes every time I run `bower install`, which seem to suggest that it isn't a particular package causing the error.

I have found several different instances of people having trouble with error #128 when cloning from behind a firewall. It has [been suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16298986/unable-to-connect-to-github-com-for-cloning) that this can be fixed by running `git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://` in order to tell git to use HTTPS as the protocol instead of git, but this hasn't fixed the issue for me. Even more confusing is the `fatal: Could not chdir to 'Y:/': No such file or directory`. I frankly don't know where this is coming from. It only seems to show up when I run certain git commands, such as `ls-remote`.

Also, I am able to manually clone via `SSH` or `HTTPS` successfully. This error only happens in Bower.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to fix this? I have searched quite a bit and have been unable to find anything else mentioning it. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Turns out this has something to do with my project being located on a network drive mounted locally via `SMB`. When I copied the project locally and ran the command, it worked. I will need to look into a better way to access samba shares with Git. If anyone has any ideas, I'm definitely open to them.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this issue. The solution for me was to add to the repository config

```
[url "https://"]
    insteadOf = git://
```

the file is in **YOUR_REPO/.git/config**

not in the global config like:

```
git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git@github.com:
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

Answer (score 0):

I just hit the same error trying out angular-seed.

However my solution was not to move the project to local disk (The project is already local). As a work around to the problems when running

```
npm install
```

I first installed the bower command and then used bower install directly to install the bower packages. With a cache clean in the middle for good measure.

```
sudo npm install -g bower
bower cache clean
bower install
```

Hopefully this will help ease the frustration for others.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue for me adding

```
[url "https:"]
    insteadOf = git:
```

To YOUR_REPO/.git/config did the trick, https without the double forward slash

Answer (score 0):

This is Because in a Proxy Environment Http and Https are preferred, So instead of

```
"devDependencies": {

    "file-loader": "^0.8.4",
    "gh-pages": "git://github.com/markdalgleish/gh-pages#cli-message",

  }
```

Replace it with Https

```
"devDependencies": {

        "file-loader": "^0.8.4",
        "gh-pages": "Https://github.com/markdalgleish/gh-pages#cli-message",

      }
```

Or you Can Set it in your Repo Globally

Good Luck!!