# npm install giving error while accessing GIT url

Tags: node.js, git, npm

my package.json has the following dependency,

```
    {
  "name": "AppName",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "App Description",
  "author": "@author",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-flip": "git://github.com/geedmo/css-flip",
    "gulp": "^3.8.10",
    "gulp-angular-htmlify": "^0.4.0",
    "gulp-changed": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-compass": "^2.0.4",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.4.1",
    "gulp-css-flip": "^0.4.0",
    "gulp-expect-file": "0.0.7",
    "gulp-filter": "^1.0.2",
    "gulp-html-prettify": "0.0.1",
    "gulp-if": "^1.2.5",
    "gulp-ignore": "^1.2.1",
    "gulp-jade": "^0.8.0",
    "gulp-jsvalidate": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-less": "^1.3.9",
    "gulp-livereload": "^2.1.1",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^0.10.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^0.3.11",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "^0.4.3",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^1.3.2",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.3.0",
    "gulp-sync": "^0.1.4",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.1",
    "marked": "^0.3.2",
    "through2": "^0.6.3",
    "yargs": "^3.7.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prestart": "bower install",
    "start": "npm install",
    "poststart": "gulp"
  }
}
```

when I execute `npm install` command, I am getting the following error,

```
npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url
npm WARN addRemoteGit
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:751:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:1183:11)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Pipe.close (net.js:485:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit  git://github.com/geedmo/css-flip.git resetting remote C:\Users\drj8cob\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-geedmo-css-flip-git-3c35004c because of error: {
 [Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url
npm WARN addRemoteGit ]
npm WARN addRemoteGit   killed: false,
npm WARN addRemoteGit   code: 1,
npm WARN addRemoteGit   signal: null,
npm WARN addRemoteGit   cmd: 'git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url' }
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\drj8cob\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git://github.com/geedmo/css-flip.git C:\Users\drj8cob\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remot
es\git-github-com-geedmo-css-flip-git-3c35004c: Cloning into bare repository 'C:\Users\drj8cob\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-geedmo-css-flip-git-3c35004c'...
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\drj8cob\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git://github.com/geedmo/css-flip.git C:\Users\drj8cob\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remot
es\git-github-com-geedmo-css-flip-git-3c35004c: fatal: Unable to look up github.com (port 9418) (No such host is known. )
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! code 128

npm ERR! Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true clone --template=C:\Users\drj8cob\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git://github.com/geedmo/css-flip.git C:\Users\drj8c
ob\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-geedmo-css-flip-git-3c35004c
npm ERR! Cloning into bare repository 'C:\Users\drj8cob\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-geedmo-css-flip-git-3c35004c'...
npm ERR! fatal: Unable to look up github.com (port 9418) (No such host is known. )
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

I am new to node modules and git. Should i have to do any configuration related to GIT in node modules?

**[Edit] :** I am behind a corporate proxy. Should have to give any configuration related to that? I added proxy details in .npmrc file in `users/<username>/.npmrc` file. My path variable has the Git/bin location as well.

Comment: Can you give the full content of the `package.json` file?

Comment: @Deepak Biswal, I have given the full content of `package.json` file.

Comment: Hey, I tried to run it at my end and everything seems to be working fine!

Comment: npm install --verbose according [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873973/npm-install-hangs/39376187)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

**This question has an answer in an other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16298986/1822974)**. The issue occurred since I was behind corporate proxy. And [@bnguyen82](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16298986/unable-to-connect-to-github-com-for-cloning/18889129#18889129)'s answer helped me finally.

I just used the following command and the issue got resolved.

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

Comment: I made this cofiguration working by removing the quotes around https:// as this: git config --global url.https://.insteadOf git://

Answer (score 22):

The accepted answer alone did not help me. Finally it worked after I cleared the npm cache using `npm cache clear`.

Comment: `As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. If you want to make sure everything is consistent, use 'npm cache verify' instead. On the other hand, if you're debugging an issue with the installer, you can use "npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cache" to use a temporary cache instead of nuking the actual one.` Output on version 10.x

Answer (score 3):

1.check your internet connection
2.ping test to github.com in TERMINAL or CMD
if everything is working fine then try to 
use this format for your git url `git+https://git@github.com/geedmo/css-flip.git`

or

if you need ssh:

`git+ssh://git@github.com/visionmedia/express.git`

Comment: the former gives fatal: unable to access https://git@github.com/geedmo/css-flip.git/: Could not resolve host: github.com  and later gives `ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: no address associated with name`

Comment: check internet connection once

Comment: I am behind a corporate proxy. Should i have to give some configuration? i have given proxy details in .npmrc file.

Comment: that error was basic , it does not resolving github.com   that means it is not in internet.

Comment: just test in your  CMD or TERMINAL as  "ping github.com"

Comment: i am not able to ping github in command prompt. But i am able to access internet through browser.

Comment: so your problem is not with npm .  if you succeed to ping github.com then your problem is solved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84795/discussion-between-drb-and-jameel-grand).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and was able to resolve it by installing git

```
sudo apt-get install git-all
```

Answer (score 1):

Git can not link to the specified URL. You can try git proxy mode. 
 **(Need their own proxy service)**

Settings：

```
git config –global http.proxy http://127.0.0.1:1080 
git config –global https.proxy https://127.0.0.1:1080
```

Cancel the setting：

```
git config –global –unset http.proxy 
git config –global –unset https.proxy
```

Answer (score 1):

in my case, the git wasn't install on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

In non-interactive mode

Git Bash in the folder where you want set up your project

```sh
expo init AwesomeProject --template blank --workflow managed --name yourappname
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Just observe this `"css-flip": "git://github.com/geedmo/css-flip"` line in your package JSON code.
2. Your project depends upon a file `css-flip` which is stored in another project/repo.
3. while installing npm, your package JSON file will try to access and download  `css-flip` file of another repo but something might blocking it.
4. In my case ***VPN*** blocked dependent files of other repo. So I initiated VPN and tried installing npm again `npm i` and it worked like magic.

Answer (score 0):

At last I kill the terminal and restart again and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'm in a Windows environment and I'm using [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) and [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/index.html). I'd installed [Cygwin's GIT version](https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/git.html) and I've got errors similar to those in the question regarding `Error: Command failed: git`.

So, I uninstalled this version and installed [GIT for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org). Then I attempted `npm i` again and the problem was solved.