# npm using Git prints error

Tags: node.js, git

I am following this tutorial:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Using_third-party_modules_(jpm)

I installed git but I got this error:

```
npm install menuitem --save
npm WARN package.json test@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url
npm WARN addRemoteGit
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:213:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:827:16)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child
_process.js:211:5)
npm WARN addRemoteGit  git+https://github.com/OverByThere/addon-pathfinder.git resetting remote C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Data aplikací\npm-cache\
_git-remotes\https-github-com-OverByThere-addon-pathfinder-git-93454c54 because of error: { [Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url
```

Anybody knows why this happens and how to solve it?

Git version: 2.9.0.windows.1

Comment: What git version are you using?

Comment: That seems ancient. Just for testing, can you try and upgrade to 2.9?

Comment: Is it like http://stackoverflow.com/q/31744852/6309? (also seen in https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8494#issuecomment-162495751)

Comment: He uses package.json some file of his choice - he said "my package" . However I have no choice, and idk which file make problems or where to find it

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? Can you configure configure git to use https instead of git, just to see if that makes any difference? (as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/31745910/6309)

Comment: I don't use proxy. I used BitTorrent years ago so no problem with connection. `git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git:/` does not help