# permission denied error with npm install

Tags: git, ubuntu, npm, gulp, npm-install

Just made a fresh reinstall of my ubuntu and installed necessarily things such as nodejs npm. If I cloned project and tried **sudo npm install** I got this error. Had someone same problem?

**using**
node: 8.9.3
npm: 5.5.1

```
fetchPackageMetaData error for gulp@git://github.com/gulpjs/gulp.git#4ed9a4a3275559c73a396eff7e1fde3824951ebb Command failed: /usr/bin/git clone -q git://github.com/gulpjs/gulp.git /home/user_name/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-0e191fc9

fetchPackageMetaData /home/user_name/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-0e191fc9/.git: Permission denied

Error: Command failed: /usr/bin/git clone -q git://github.com/gulpjs/gulp.git /home/user_name/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-0e191fc9

/home/user_name/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-0e191fc9/.git: Permission denied
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31744852/npm-install-giving-error-while-accessing-git-url This question may help.

Comment: npm comes installed together with install of node ... I avoid using sudo ... if you do install node using sudo then all npm install commands must also issue sudo ... if you avoid sudo during install then never use `sudo npm install x` ... install without sudo can be either a raw source code install or a compiled install ... read the inline comments     https://askubuntu.com/questions/426750/how-can-i-update-my-nodejs-to-the-latest-version/959382#959382

Answer (score 39, accepted):

this solution worked for me

```
 sudo sudo npm install
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: ...especially that double `sudo` would warrant some explanation beyond "I threw commands at the wall to see what would stick".

Comment: This solution looks stupid but actually very genious and worked out for me :D

Comment: It worked for me too, so checked the idea behind `sudo sudo`. The reason why it works, is that the second `sudo` is invoked as root which has the permissions to impersonate other users without requiring a password. So the command that previously gave Permission deny, works - because of the way sudo is configured (`NOPASSWD:` in sudoers) it doesn't need a password to execute as root.

Comment: Beat me to it, how come we are writing explanation one year after the answer at the exact same time? :)

Comment: incredible, worked out for me. Thanks **Nikita Kurtin** for description

Answer (score 2):

Here what worked for me:
login as root,and type

```
sudo su
npm install -g npm
```

Not sure if it's the same problem i had, but worth a try.

Comment: I had a similar problem using webpack encore, and this helps. Thank You! Can You provide more information what this actually does?

Comment: reinstall npm globally

Comment: It works! — I love you.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case the above solution doesn't work, try running:

`sudo npm install --unsafe-perm=true`