# Unable to clone Buildroot repository

Tags: git, buildroot

I'am trying to clone [buildroot repository](https://git.busybox.net/buildroot/) by utilising the following command:

```
> git clone https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot.git
Cloning into 'buildroot'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot.git/': Could not resolve host: github.com
```

Could you please help me undrestand what's wrong with this command ?

**EDIT**

The result of `nslookup github.com` is:

```
> nslookup github.com
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 192.168.249.10, trying next server
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Comment: The command is fine, it seems your network setup has issues. Git can't resolve the domain `github.com`.

Comment: @sebasgo thank u , i can access the link with the browser, "network setup" you mean there is firewalls or sth else , how can i check ?

Comment: are u able to clone some other repositories

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16298986/unable-to-connect-to-github-com-for-cloning?rq=1

Comment: It seems there is something wrong with your DNS resolution. The browser might have the name-resolution cached and thus still open the URL while Git cannot. Can you do `nslookup github.com`?

Comment: @Deepak Mahakale , no i'am not able to clone other repo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [could not resolve host github.com error while cloning remote repository in git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20370294/could-not-resolve-host-github-com-error-while-cloning-remote-repository-in-git)

Comment: @Mouin as Deepak said, do you work somewhere where you have to use an HTTP proxy, then configure it. If not, talk to your IT to get this issue resolved. It is an infrastructure problem like sebasgo said.

Comment: @Vampire, thank you , the problem is resolved i configure HTTPS_PROXY environement variable to be the same as the browser proxy config and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is resolved.

What i have done :
On firefox browser

```
  preferences
     advanced:network:settings
```

There is proxy settings of the browser `HTTP Proxy=my_proxy` and `Port=my_port`.

I configure `HTTPS_PROXY` as follow:

```
export HTTPS_PROXY=my_proxy:my_port
```

And the cloning works as expected.

I go on this solution because the link can be opened with a browser and not with the command line, so surely there is a missing confguration in shell env variable.

similar question(pointed by @Deepak Mahakale) : [could not resolve host github.com error while cloning remote repository in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20370294/could-not-resolve-host-github-com-error-while-cloning-remote-repository-in-gitl)