# Error when installing bower package

Tags: bower

I get an error when I try to install a bower packeg.

My error :

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Anthony:Front-End anthonycluse$ bower install flexslider
bower cached        git://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider.git#ce5441b214
bower validate      ce5441b214 against git://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider.git#*
bower ECMDERR       Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider.git", exit code of #128

Additional error details:
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 192.30.252.131]: errno=Connection refused
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git / Bower Errors: Exit Code # 128 & Failed connect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21544803/git-bower-errors-exit-code-128-failed-connect)

Answer (score 4):

The error may be due to proxy/certificate connectivity issues, try following command for the error exit code of #128

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```