# Bower Install error: Unable to connect & exit code of #128

Tags: angularjs, git, bower, bower-install

I am facing an issue on bower install.

> bower ECMDERR       Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads
>   HTTPS_LINK to bower-angular-mocks.git", exit code of #128

I followed suggestions mentioned in [Git / Bower Errors: Exit Code # 128 & Failed connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21544803/git-bower-errors-exit-code-128-failed-connect).  I have made the recommended proxy settings for both GIT & Bower.

.bowerrc

```
"proxy" : "PROXY_URL",
"https-proxy" : "PROXY_URL"
```

GIT

```
http.proxy=PROXY_URL
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git:// [GIT config to use HTTPS in place of GIT]
```

### Here is my complete error log:

```
bower not-cached    HTTPS_LINK to bower-angular.git#1.2.x
bower resolve       HTTPS_LINK to bower-angular.git#1.2.x
bower not-cached    HTTPS_LINK to bower-angular-loader.git#1.2.x
bower resolve       HTTPS_LINK to bower-angular-loader.git#1.2.x
bower not-cached    HTTPS_LINK to bower-angular-route.git#1.2.x
bower resolve       HTTPS_LINK to bower-angular-route.git#1.2.x
bower not-cached    HTTPS_LINK to html5-boilerplate.git#~4.3.0
bower resolve       HTTPS_LINK to html5-boilerplate.git#~4.3.0
bower not-cached    HTTPS_LINK to bower-angular-mocks.git#~1.2.x
bower resolve       HTTPS_LINK to bower-angular-mocks.git#~1.2.x
bower ECMDERR       Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads https://gith
ub.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks.git", exit code of #128

Additional error details:
fatal: unable to access '**https://**github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks.git/': F
ailed connect to github.com:443; No error
```

From a log I can see that bower is using HTTPS instead of GIT. And another update is that I am able to execute the failed command on GIT.

```
git ls-remote --tags --heads HTTPS_LINK
```

Comment: The error is resolved once i add the "http_proxy" & "https_proxy" environment variables. If still have issues, try once restarting the sytem :)

So for npm install to work properly, i had configured proxy settings  in GIT, Borrower (.bowerrc file), npm & Envrionment variables.

Comment: Can you please  update your question with the answer or add an answer with everything you did? You can accept that as the answer. I will upvote both your question and answer.

Answer (score 8):

I was having a similar issues where bower failed to get angular-animate. I was able to resolve this issue by running

**git config --global url."https://".insteadOf "git://"**

Make sure you navigate to your App project folder and run that to see if that would resolve your issues

Answer (score 4):

If it is a new project type git init in order to create a git repository in your project directory, then try this

```
git config --local url."https://".insteadOf "git://"
```

This configuration will only affect local project

Then try bower commands

If you want a global solution try this

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

A deeper explanation in this url: http://jgoodall.me/posts/2013/05/29/git-use-https/

Answer (score 2):

I have had this issue and deleting C:\user\AppData\Roaming\bower\cache clears it up for me

Answer (score 1):

Running the "bower install" in git bash, cleaning the C:\Users\\AppData\Local\bower, run "git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://" then "bower cache clean". Finally "bower install" all in Giy Bash.