# How to install Polymer iron-elements using bower?

Tags: html, polymer, bower, bower-install

How to install polymer iron and paper elements for Polymer 0.9 using bower? Tried using bower to install in a way similar to core-elements but fails. Migration guide doesn't provide any information on upgrading core/iron or paper elements.

```
bower install Polymer/iron-elements#^0.9.0

bower iron-elements#^0.9.0  not-cached git://github.com/Polymer/iron-elements.git#^0.9.0
bower iron-elements#^0.9.0     resolve git://github.com/Polymer/iron-elements.git#^0.9.0
bower iron-elements#^0.9.0     ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/Polymer/iron-elements.git", exit code of #128 fatal: remote error:    Repository not found.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The new 0.9 elements are [here](https://github.com/polymerelements).
You get them with bower this way:

```
bower install polymerelements/iron-ajax
```

I don't think there's an entire element collection ready yet, you should probably download every single needed element.

You can find more info about the new elements in the [0.9 release info](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.9/):

> **Where did the elements go?**
>   Not all elements have been ported to the
>   current release, but we’re porting them as fast as we can. You can
>   find work-in-progress versions of many elements in the [PolymerElements
>   GitHub organization](https://github.com/PolymerElements).
>
> The elements are being reorganized into more consistent product lines,
>   including:
>
> Iron elements. Basic elements that don’t express a visual style. Most
>   of the old core- elements are being renamed to iron-. Some former
>   core- elements that implemented material design (such as core-toolbar,
>   core-menu, core-header-panel) are being migrated to paper-.
>
> Paper elements. Material design elements. All of the old paper-
>   elements, plus a few of the old core- elements.
>
> Neon elements. Animation elements.
>
> These element sets will be launching with their own site sometime
>   around the Polymer 1.0 timeframe. The new site will include API docs
>   for the elements. If you want to get started with the work-in-progress
>   versions, the individual repos are the best source for information
>   about the elements right now.
>
> You can also check out the community Road to Polymer project which is
>   tracking the status of Polymer elements.

Also, you may find some valualble info in the [Polymer Blog](https://blog.polymer-project.org/). Stay tuned!

Answer (score 11):

Thanks Matteo. Adding to Matteo's answer we can install all available ported iron and paper elements for Polymer 0.9.0 using the following bower commands

```
bower install polymerelements/iron-elements
bower install polymerelements/paper-elements
```

Answer (score 3):

for any elements installation, first go to element's page:
    https://elements.polymer-project.org/
and find the element you want. while inside the element's page, in the left hand side, there is **'Bower Command'** section. 
just copy that and paste it in your shell/terminal/command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error as you reported, and was unable to install any elements using bower as proposed above. However, everything worked after running following command in my project folder:

```
git config --local url."https://".insteadOf "git://"
```

Here you may find more details about this solution:
[Bower Install error: Unable to connect & exit code of #128](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25891884/bower-install-error-unable-to-connect-exit-code-of-128?rq=1)