# Visual studio 2015 Tools for Apache Cordova

Tags: git, visual-studio, cordova, bower

I have some problems with the Tools for Apache Cordova template.

I'm working on a newly installed `windows 10 OS`, only thing installed is VS 2015 and Chrome.

*The Windows firewall is disabled and I'm not behind any proxies.*

*The problem is when I create a new "Blank App (Apache Cordova)" project on my `C:\\` drive and add some bower dependencies everything works perfect.*

**If I do the same on another drive, in this case `E:\\`, the bower dependencies restore dependencies does not work, I'm getting the follwing in my output window.**

> PATH=E:\workplace\projects\Itchy\Itchy.\node_modules.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External;%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\git
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\Bower.cmd" install --force-latest
>   bower jquery#2.1.4              cached git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#2.1.4
>   bower jquery#2.1.4            validate 2.1.4 against git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#2.1.4
>   bower jquery#2.1.4             ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git", exit code of #128

Hoping someone can help with this.

**UPDATE: #1**

Tried some new things

1. Added the git to my environment variables by adding the following
       to the path variables: **"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;"**
2. Open a command prompt. Entered **git config --list** from the **c:\**.
       Everything works like a charm.
3. Changed to the **e:\** and entered **git config --list**. Got a
           permission denied to **i:\**. (I don't have a i:\ drive)

Comment: Hey @Mesomorf, welcome to SO. Have you tried the solutions in the following question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21544803/git-bower-errors-exit-code-128-failed-connect

Comment: Yes. I have tried that one too. But Visual studio does not use .getconfig. So I tried to install a git manually and change the git settings in Visual studio, but nothing changed.

Comment: Maybe I should metion that I'm a newbee, when talking about git and cordova.

Comment: maybe it's a just a typo, but you tried with `.gitconfig`, right?

Comment: yes. of course. My bad.