# Git ignoring global settings on TeamCity agent

Tags: git, teamcity, bower

I've been struggling for 8 working days solid to get npm, grunt and bower to work on our TC server (I've given up on our dev PCs behind the proxy).

On a few occasions the problem seems to be that when npm is installing a tool or bower is doing whatever it does, git ignores global settings.

The most recent problem is that some bower thing is trying to list some tags on a remote github repo, but is using `git://` instead of HTTPS.

This can be solved with the following QA:

[Git / Bower Errors: Exit Code # 128 & Failed connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21544803/git-bower-errors-exit-code-128-failed-connect)

I can now run the failing command (including `git://`) at a prompt from the build agent VM successfully, but when TeamCity builds, it still fails.

Either TeamCity or bower or something is not running git in the way its run from the command line. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My colleague thinks its because `--global` is per user, which seems so obvious now, and as such, the TeamCity agent identity/profile knows not of the config I set at the command line.

Update: we copied the Git settings file between the profile folders and its all running, finally. FINALLY.