# Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection refused in terminal MacBook

Tags: xcode, git, macos, terminal, carthage

Hi i am trying to clone the Bitbucket iOS project using Https using the Git Desktop Client . It clones well and good to the local machine. But when i try to install some dependencies through the Carthage command:

```
carthage bootstrap --platform iOS
```

I get the foloowing error in the terminal: I am working from the company proxy:

```
MacLions-MacBook-Pro:ios MacLions$ carthage bootstrap --platform iOS
*** Checking out dashboard at "v0.2.1"
*** Checking out credential-recovery at "v0.2.1"
*** Checking out Alamofire at "4.8.1"
*** Checking out secureDataStorage at "v0.0.2"
*** Cloning Alamofire
*** Cloning info-recovery
A shell task (/usr/bin/env git clone --bare --quiet https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git /Users/MacLions/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/dependencies/Alamofire) failed with exit code 128:
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Connection refused
```

I tried setting up with the proxy in git :

[Getting git to work with a proxy server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783811/getting-git-to-work-with-a-proxy-server)

But still no success

Answer (score 0):

I'm not Mac user. Just Googled it and found some answers.
Removing `~/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit` may help. 
Reference - https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/694. 
And this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21544803/git-bower-errors-exit-code-128-failed-connect) may help you.