# Trouble building AngularJS UI-Grid with Grunt and Node.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, gruntjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm new to Node.js, Github, Grunt and the other tools used on the ui-grid project. I'm trying to follow the instructions at https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/blob/master/FIRST_TIMER.md to get started.

Its going well, but when I run the grunt task, I get an error:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Windows 7) ERROR
  ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery
  at c:/Users/russell/ng-grid/lib/test/jquery.simulate.js:328


Warning: Task "karma:angular-1.2.14" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I tried to execute the next command `grunt install` and got the following error:

```
>> bower csv-js#* ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/gkindel/CSV-JS.git", 
   exit code of #128 Warning: Done, with errors. Use --force to continue. Aborted due to warnings
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: I tried to execute the next command (grunt install) and got the following error:>> bower csv-js#*                             ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/gkindel/CSV-JS.git", exit code of #128
Warning: Done, with errors. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

Answer (score 2):

[This thread](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/689) says that the problem is that you are using the git protocol instead of https. Try this:

```
$ git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

You can also read more about it at this [stack overflow thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15669091/bower-install-using-only-https)

Comment: That fixed that issue , now when I run the end to end tests I get$ grunt test:e2e
Running "connect:testserver" (connect) task
Started connect web server on 127.0.0.1:9999.

Running "protractor:singlerun" (protractor) task
Starting selenium standalone server...

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:1001:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:792:34)
>>
Fatal error: protractor exited with code: 8