# grunt bower:install error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, gruntjs, bower

I am a beginner in angularJS, and i want to start node server with `npm start` on a bitbucket cloned project but I get an error when doing this.

I tried a couple of things, unblock port 22 from the firewall in-going and out-going settings and run this command `npm install -g grunt-cli` but with no effect, i still get this error

this is my npm-debug file:

```html
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install' ]
2 info using npm@1.4.28
3 info using node@v0.10.36
4 verbose node symlink C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe
5 warn package.json wkfs-demo@0.1.0 No repository field.
6 warn package.json wkfs-demo@0.1.0 No README data
7 verbose readDependencies using package.json deps
8 verbose install where, deps [ 'C:\\angular_project\\wkfs-demo',
8 verbose install   [ 'grunt',
8 verbose install     'grunt-typescript',
8 verbose install     'grunt-tslint',
8 verbose install     'grunt-tsd',
8 verbose install     'grunt-angular-templates',
8 verbose install     'grunt-bower-task',
8 verbose install     'grunt-eslint',
8 verbose install     'grunt-contrib-clean',
8 verbose install     'grunt-contrib-concat',
8 verbose install     'grunt-contrib-copy',
8 verbose install     'grunt-contrib-uglify',
8 verbose install     'grunt-contrib-cssmin',
8 verbose install     'grunt-ng-annotate',
8 verbose install     'grunt-usemin',
8 verbose install     'time-grunt',
8 verbose install     'grunt-karma',
8 verbose install     'grunt-protractor-runner',
8 verbose install     'grunt-protractor-webdriver',
8 verbose install     'karma-chrome-launcher',
8 verbose install     'karma-coverage',
8 verbose install     'karma-html-reporter',
8 verbose install     'karma-jasmine',
8 verbose install     'karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor',
8 verbose install     'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
8 verbose install     'protractor',
8 verbose install     'http-server' ] ]
9 info preinstall wkfs-demo@0.1.0
10 verbose readDependencies using package.json deps
11 verbose already installed skipping grunt@~0.4.5 C:\angular_project\wkfs-demo
12 verbose already installed skipping grunt-typescript@~0.4.6 C:\angular_project\wkfs-demo
13 verbose already installed skipping grunt-tslint@^1.0.1 C:\angular_project\wkfs-demo
14 verbose cache add [ 'grunt-tsd@next', null ]
15 verbose cache add name=undefined spec="grunt-tsd@next" args=["grunt-tsd@next",null]
16 verbose parsed url { protocol: null,
16 verbose parsed url   slashes: null,
16 verbose parsed url   auth: null,
16 verbose parsed url   host: null,
16 verbose parsed url   port: null,
16 verbose parsed url   hostname: null,
16 verbose parsed url   hash: null,
16 verbose parsed url   search: null,
16 verbose parsed url   query: null,
16 verbose parsed url   pathname: 'grunt-tsd@next',
16 verbose parsed url   path: 'grunt-tsd@next',
16 verbose parsed url   href: 'grunt-tsd@next' }
17 verbose already installed skipping grunt-angular-templates@~0.5.7 C:\angular_project\wkfs-demo
18 verbose already installed skipping grunt-bower-task@^0.4.0 C:\angular_project\wkfs-demo
19 verbose already installed skipping grunt-eslint@^2.0.0 C:\angular_project\wkfs-demo
20 verbose already installed skipping grunt-contrib-clean@^0.6.0 C:\angular_project\wkfs-demo
21 verbose already installed skipping grunt-contrib-concat@^0.5.0 C:\angular_project\wkfs-demo
22 verbose already installed skipping grunt-contrib-copy@^0.7.0 C:\angular_project\wkfs-demo
23 verbose already installed skipping grunt-contrib-uglify@^0.6.0 C:\angular_project\wkfs-demo
24 verbose already installed skipping grunt-contrib-cssmin@^0.10.0 C:\angular_project\wkfs-demo
25 verbose already installed skipping grunt-ng-annotate@^0.7.0 C:\angular_project\wkfs-demo
26 verbose already installed skipping grunt-usemin@^2.6.2 C:\angular_project\wkfs-demo
27 verbose already installed skipping time-grunt@^1.0.0 C:\angular_project\wkfs-demo
28 verbose already installed skipping grunt-karma@0.9.0 C:\angular_project\wkfs-demo
29 verbose already installed skipping grunt-protractor-runner@^1.1.4 C:\angular_project\wkfs-demo
30 verbose cache add name="grunt-tsd" spec="next" args=["grunt-tsd","next"]
31 verbose parsed url { protocol: null,
31 verbose parsed url   slashes: null,
31 verbose parsed url   auth: null,
31 verbose parsed url   host: null,
31 verbose parsed url   port: null,
31 verbose parsed url   hostname: null,
31 verbose parsed url   hash: null,
31 verbose parsed url   search: null,
31 verbose parsed url   query: null,
31 verbose parsed url   pathname: 'next',
31 verbose parsed url   path: 'next',
31 verbose parsed url   href: 'next' }
32 verbose addNamed [ 'grunt-tsd', 'next' ]
33 verbose addNamed [ null, null ]
34 silly lockFile f5640f9e-grunt-tsd-next grunt-tsd@next
35 verbose lock grunt-tsd@next C:\Users\aurel.deac\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\f5640f9e-grunt-tsd-next.lock
36 info addNameTag [ 'grunt-tsd', 'next' ]
37 verbose request where is /grunt-tsd
38 verbose request registry http://int-build.wkfs-frc.local:4873/
39 verbose request id d2a1ac53e4175bbc
40 verbose url raw /grunt-tsd
41 verbose url resolving [ 'http://int-build.wkfs-frc.local:4873/', './grunt-tsd' ]
42 verbose url resolved http://int-build.wkfs-frc.local:4873/grunt-tsd
43 verbose request where is http://int-build.wkfs-frc.local:4873/grunt-tsd
44 info trying registry request attempt 1 at 12:20:54
45 verbose etag "e12d92cab773b8405bf82b2507fb6c5f"
46 http GET http://int-build.wkfs-frc.local:4873/grunt-tsd
47 verbose already installed skipping grunt-protractor-webdriver@^0.1.9 C:\angular_project\wkfs-demo
48 verbose already installed skipping karma-chrome-launcher@^0.1.5 C:\angular_project\wkfs-demo
49 verbose already installed skipping karma-coverage@^0.2.6 C:\angular_project\wkfs-demo
50 verbose already installed skipping karma-html-reporter@^0.2.4 C:\angular_project\wkfs-demo
51 verbose already installed skipping karma-jasmine@^0.2.3 C:\angular_project\wkfs-demo
52 verbose already installed skipping karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor@~0.1 C:\angular_project\wkfs-demo
53 verbose already installed skipping karma-phantomjs-launcher@^0.1.4 C:\angular_project\wkfs-demo
54 verbose already installed skipping protractor@^1.3.1 C:\angular_project\wkfs-demo
55 verbose already installed skipping http-server@^0.7.4 C:\angular_project\wkfs-demo
56 http 304 http://int-build.wkfs-frc.local:4873/grunt-tsd
57 silly registry.get cb [ 304,
57 silly registry.get   { 'x-powered-by': 'Sinopia/1.0.1',
57 silly registry.get     etag: '"e12d92cab773b8405bf82b2507fb6c5f"',
57 silly registry.get     'x-status-cat': 'http://flic.kr/p/aXY3dH',
57 silly registry.get     date: 'Tue, 10 Mar 2015 10:19:35 GMT',
57 silly registry.get     connection: 'keep-alive' } ]
58 verbose etag http://int-build.wkfs-frc.local:4873/grunt-tsd from cache
59 verbose addNamed [ 'grunt-tsd', '0.2.0-beta.1' ]
60 verbose addNamed [ '0.2.0-beta.1', '0.2.0-beta.1' ]
61 silly lockFile 18eefc5b-grunt-tsd-0-2-0-beta-1 grunt-tsd@0.2.0-beta.1
62 verbose lock grunt-tsd@0.2.0-beta.1 C:\Users\aurel.deac\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\18eefc5b-grunt-tsd-0-2-0-beta-1.lock
63 silly lockFile 18eefc5b-grunt-tsd-0-2-0-beta-1 grunt-tsd@0.2.0-beta.1
64 silly lockFile 18eefc5b-grunt-tsd-0-2-0-beta-1 grunt-tsd@0.2.0-beta.1
65 silly lockFile f5640f9e-grunt-tsd-next grunt-tsd@next
66 silly lockFile f5640f9e-grunt-tsd-next grunt-tsd@next
67 info already installed grunt-tsd@0.2.0-beta.1
68 silly resolved []
69 info build C:\angular_project\wkfs-demo
70 verbose linkStuff [ false, false, false, 'C:\\angular_project' ]
71 info linkStuff wkfs-demo@0.1.0
72 verbose linkBins wkfs-demo@0.1.0
73 verbose linkMans wkfs-demo@0.1.0
74 verbose rebuildBundles wkfs-demo@0.1.0
75 verbose rebuildBundles [ '.bin',
75 verbose rebuildBundles   'bower',
75 verbose rebuildBundles   'grunt',
75 verbose rebuildBundles   'grunt-angular-templates',
75 verbose rebuildBundles   'grunt-bower-task',
75 verbose rebuildBundles   'grunt-contrib-clean',
75 verbose rebuildBundles   'grunt-contrib-concat',
75 verbose rebuildBundles   'grunt-contrib-copy',
75 verbose rebuildBundles   'grunt-contrib-cssmin',
75 verbose rebuildBundles   'grunt-contrib-uglify',
75 verbose rebuildBundles   'grunt-eslint',
75 verbose rebuildBundles   'grunt-karma',
75 verbose rebuildBundles   'grunt-ng-annotate',
75 verbose rebuildBundles   'grunt-protractor-runner',
75 verbose rebuildBundles   'grunt-protractor-webdriver',
75 verbose rebuildBundles   'grunt-tsd',
75 verbose rebuildBundles   'grunt-tslint',
75 verbose rebuildBundles   'grunt-typescript',
75 verbose rebuildBundles   'grunt-usemin',
75 verbose rebuildBundles   'http-server',
75 verbose rebuildBundles   'karma',
75 verbose rebuildBundles   'karma-chrome-launcher',
75 verbose rebuildBundles   'karma-coverage',
75 verbose rebuildBundles   'karma-html-reporter',
75 verbose rebuildBundles   'karma-jasmine',
75 verbose rebuildBundles   'karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor',
75 verbose rebuildBundles   'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
75 verbose rebuildBundles   'protractor',
75 verbose rebuildBundles   'time-grunt',
75 verbose rebuildBundles   'typescript' ]
76 verbose rebuild bundle C:\angular_project\wkfs-demo\node_modules\bower
77 info build C:\angular_project\wkfs-demo\node_modules\bower
78 info preinstall bower@1.3.12
79 verbose linkStuff [ false,
79 verbose linkStuff   false,
79 verbose linkStuff   false,
79 verbose linkStuff   'C:\\angular_project\\wkfs-demo\\node_modules' ]
80 info linkStuff bower@1.3.12
81 warn prefer global bower@1.3.12 should be installed with -g
82 verbose linkBins bower@1.3.12
83 verbose link bins [ { bower: 'bin/bower' },
83 verbose link bins   'C:\\angular_project\\wkfs-demo\\node_modules\\.bin',
83 verbose link bins   false ]
84 verbose linkMans bower@1.3.12
85 verbose rebuildBundles bower@1.3.12
86 verbose rebuildBundles [ '.bin',
86 verbose rebuildBundles   'abbrev',
86 verbose rebuildBundles   'archy',
86 verbose rebuildBundles   'bower-config',
86 verbose rebuildBundles   'bower-endpoint-parser',
86 verbose rebuildBundles   'bower-json',
86 verbose rebuildBundles   'bower-logger',
86 verbose rebuildBundles   'bower-registry-client',
86 verbose rebuildBundles   'cardinal',
86 verbose rebuildBundles   'chalk',
86 verbose rebuildBundles   'chmodr',
86 verbose rebuildBundles   'decompress-zip',
86 verbose rebuildBundles   'fstream',
86 verbose rebuildBundles   'fstream-ignore',
86 verbose rebuildBundles   'glob',
86 verbose rebuildBundles   'graceful-fs',
86 verbose rebuildBundles   'handlebars',
86 verbose rebuildBundles   'inquirer',
86 verbose rebuildBundles   'insight',
86 verbose rebuildBundles   'is-root',
86 verbose rebuildBundles   'junk',
86 verbose rebuildBundles   'lockfile',
86 verbose rebuildBundles   'lru-cache',
86 verbose rebuildBundles   'mkdirp',
86 verbose rebuildBundles   'mout',
86 verbose rebuildBundles   'nopt',
86 verbose rebuildBundles   'opn',
86 verbose rebuildBundles   'osenv',
86 verbose rebuildBundles   'p-throttler',
86 verbose rebuildBundles   'promptly',
86 verbose rebuildBundles   'q',
86 verbose rebuildBundles   'request',
86 verbose rebuildBundles   'request-progress',
86 verbose rebuildBundles   'retry',
86 verbose rebuildBundles   'rimraf',
86 verbose rebuildBundles   'semver',
86 verbose rebuildBundles   'shell-quote',
86 verbose rebuildBundles   'stringify-object',
86 verbose rebuildBundles   'tar-fs',
86 verbose rebuildBundles   'tmp',
86 verbose rebuildBundles   'update-notifier',
86 verbose rebuildBundles   'which' ]
87 info install bower@1.3.12
88 info postinstall bower@1.3.12
89 verbose rebuild bundle C:\angular_project\wkfs-demo\node_modules\karma
90 info build C:\angular_project\wkfs-demo\node_modules\karma
91 info preinstall karma@0.12.31
92 verbose linkStuff [ false,
92 verbose linkStuff   false,
92 verbose linkStuff   false,
92 verbose linkStuff   'C:\\angular_project\\wkfs-demo\\node_modules' ]
93 info linkStuff karma@0.12.31
94 verbose linkBins karma@0.12.31
95 verbose link bins [ {},
95 verbose link bins   'C:\\angular_project\\wkfs-demo\\node_modules\\.bin',
95 verbose link bins   false ]
96 verbose linkMans karma@0.12.31
97 verbose rebuildBundles karma@0.12.31
98 verbose rebuildBundles [ '.bin',
98 verbose rebuildBundles   'chokidar',
98 verbose rebuildBundles   'colors',
98 verbose rebuildBundles   'connect',
98 verbose rebuildBundles   'di',
98 verbose rebuildBundles   'glob',
98 verbose rebuildBundles   'graceful-fs',
98 verbose rebuildBundles   'http-proxy',
98 verbose rebuildBundles   'lodash',
98 verbose rebuildBundles   'log4js',
98 verbose rebuildBundles   'mime',
98 verbose rebuildBundles   'minimatch',
98 verbose rebuildBundles   'optimist',
98 verbose rebuildBundles   'q',
98 verbose rebuildBundles   'rimraf',
98 verbose rebuildBundles   'socket.io',
98 verbose rebuildBundles   'source-map',
98 verbose rebuildBundles   'useragent' ]
99 info install karma@0.12.31
100 info postinstall karma@0.12.31
101 verbose rebuild bundle C:\angular_project\wkfs-demo\node_modules\typescript
102 info build C:\angular_project\wkfs-demo\node_modules\typescript
103 info preinstall typescript@1.3.0
104 verbose linkStuff [ false,
104 verbose linkStuff   false,
104 verbose linkStuff   false,
104 verbose linkStuff   'C:\\angular_project\\wkfs-demo\\node_modules' ]
105 info linkStuff typescript@1.3.0
106 warn prefer global typescript@1.3.0 should be installed with -g
107 verbose linkBins typescript@1.3.0
108 verbose link bins [ { tsc: './bin/tsc' },
108 verbose link bins   'C:\\angular_project\\wkfs-demo\\node_modules\\.bin',
108 verbose link bins   false ]
109 verbose linkMans typescript@1.3.0
110 verbose rebuildBundles typescript@1.3.0
111 info install typescript@1.3.0
112 info postinstall typescript@1.3.0
113 info install wkfs-demo@0.1.0
114 info postinstall wkfs-demo@0.1.0
115 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
116 info wkfs-demo@0.1.0 Failed to exec postinstall script
117 error wkfs-demo@0.1.0 postinstall: `grunt bower:install`
117 error Exit status 1
118 error Failed at the wkfs-demo@0.1.0 postinstall script.
118 error This is most likely a problem with the wkfs-demo package,
118 error not with npm itself.
118 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
118 error     grunt bower:install
118 error You can get their info via:
118 error     npm owner ls wkfs-demo
118 error There is likely additional logging output above.
119 error System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
120 error command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
121 error cwd C:\angular_project\wkfs-demo
122 error node -v v0.10.36
123 error npm -v 1.4.28
124 error code ELIFECYCLE
125 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

when i run `grunt bower:install` I am getting

```
Fatal error: Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/angular/bowler-angular-route.git", exit code of #128
```

this is the package.json file:

```
    {
  "name": "wkfs-demo",
  "namelower": "wkfs-demo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "WKFS Angular.js Demo",
  "author": "wkfs-frc",
  "main": " ",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-typescript": "~0.4.6",
    "grunt-tslint": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-tsd": "next",
    "grunt-angular-templates": "~0.5.7",
    "grunt-bower-task": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-eslint": "^2.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^0.10.0",
    "grunt-ng-annotate": "^0.7.0",
    "grunt-usemin": "^2.6.2",
    "time-grunt": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-karma": "0.9.0",
    "grunt-protractor-runner": "^1.1.4",
    "grunt-protractor-webdriver": "^0.1.9",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.1.5",
    "karma-coverage": "^0.2.6",
    "karma-html-reporter": "^0.2.4",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.2.3",
    "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "~0.1",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.1.4",
    "protractor": "^1.3.1",
    "http-server": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "grunt bower:install",

    "prestart": "npm install",
    "start": "http-server -a 0.0.0.0 -p 8000"
  }
}
```

and bower.json file:

```
{
  "name": "wkfs-demo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "WKFS Angular.js Demo",
  "authors": [
    "wkfs-frc"
  ],
  "private": true,
  "ignore": [
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.3.0",
    "angular-resource": "1.3.0",
    "angular-route": "1.3.0",
    "jquery": "2.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "1.3.0"
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi, I had this issue, it was related to my school internet firewall. Can you try the install from another internet point ?

Comment: i will try this from the wireless network but donno if will work, anyhow thanks! :)

Comment: I bet it's gonna work, waiting for your feedback. Cheers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15669091/bower-install-using-only-https) was `git config --global url."https://".insteadOf http://` which means that you make git replace the protocol. I think that this configures git to use the https port and not the default git port which is 22 which is blocked or something. I would appreciate a much clearer explanation.